# AVAudioRecorder not working

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiorecorder

Unable to get the code for `AVAudioRecorder` to work with URL. Has someone been able to get Record Audio working on iOS and Swift 3? The bold text below is where I get the following error:

> "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'AVAudioRecorder' with an argument list of type '(url: URL, settings..."

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    //Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func setupRecorder(){
    let recordSettings = [AVFormatIDKey : kAudioFormatAppleLossless,
                          AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.max.rawValue,
                          AVEncoderBitRateKey : 320000,
                          AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 2,
                          AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0 ] as [String : Any]

    var error : NSError?

    func getCacheDirectory() -> String {
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.cachesDirectory,.userDomainMask, true)

        return paths [0]
    }

    func getFileURL() -> URL {
        let path = (getCacheDirectory() as NSString).strings(byAppendingPaths: ["fileName"])
        let filePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: "path")
        return filePath
    }

    // Error on the following line
    soundRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: getFileURL() as URL, settings: recordSettings, error: &error)


    if let err = error {
        NSLog("There was an error")
    }
    else {
        soundRecorder.delegate = self
        soundRecorder.prepareToRecord()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift you don't provide the `error` parameter since it `throws`.

Change this:

```
soundRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: getFileURL() as URL, settings: recordSettings, error: &error)
```

to:

```
soundRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: getFileURL() as URL, settings: recordSettings)
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! I will put it in a do/catch and execute.

Comment: New user, it says <15 level my up vote doesn't count, sorry. But grateful still :)